# iOS Review Process, SMS Verification

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

We developed a VOIP app and are pretty much done now, so I wanted to send the app into the review process but I need to provide a example / demo account which is no problem but Im not sure what to do about our SMS verification?
If we are providing a demo account the tester still has to verify his number like you know from whatsapp.

Has anyone expierence with this ?

Does apple accept this or do I have to code a workaround for the specific apple demo account ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our app requires a SMS activation as well and Apple never complained about that. The app is not usable without SMS activation and there is no way to provide a test account either.

Comment: So did they even try the SMS activation ?

Comment: We had rejections because of other things in the app, so they had to do the SMS activation at some point

Comment: Hi @hashier! I'm in a quite similar situation right now just with another constraint... Our App is targeted towards the european market and our sms provider doesn't support sending SMS to abroad numbers... Was your product available & sms-activatable worldwide?

Comment: @gasparuff Yes it was available worldwide and our provider sent messages everywhere. Or at least I never heard of any countries that had problems. Our user base was mostly located in some of the countries.